It looks like I voted even though I have used up all of my daily votes
For some reason, when I attempt to vote after having reached the daily vote limit, it will still look like I voted (it didn't actually count the votes). Could this be fixed?



What happened after you refreshed the page and the toast disappears? Is the upvote arrow still blue? I guess not, but just checking.

No it’s not @PeterJames

I think there are plenty of places in the UI here where a "widget" changes state in the UI, yet that change is not reflected in the database and a simple refresh of the page sets everything back to normal. I am not sure that this would count as a bug, maybe just an idiosyncrasy. For example, I can mouse over a vote button, click on it, and then move the mouse pointer away (while still pressing on the mouse button) and the vote button remains blue, even though I did not click.
